# How can I pass parameters to nested resources for single table inheritance in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, parameter-passing, single-table-inheritance

I am having some difficulties passing in parameters to my controller. I created an Single table inheritance model in my model file.

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
class AdvertiserAccount < Account
end
class PublisherAccount < Account
end
```

I setted up my routes table with nested resources

```
resources :advertiser_accounts do
    resources :campaigns
end
```

I want to be able to pass the current account_id (an account_id from one of my two subclasses of account) to my campaign controller file.
A URL that I would use is http://127.0.0.1:3000/advertiser_accounts/1/campaigns
Since my resource for the url is advertiser_accounts and not accounts, I am not able to get the parameter :account_id.

```
class CampaignsController < ApplicationController
def index
    @account = current_user.accounts.find_by_id(params[:account_id])
end
end
```

is there a shortcut to get the current resource or the id? Am I passing in parameters correctly? It seems confusing to call many find_by_id in the controller. Any help is appreciated.

**Edit Possible solution:**
One of the solutions that I was thinking was setting a type in my routes and then in my controller I would use case statement then get params[:advertiser_account_id] but that seems very tedious and messy. Especially if I will need to copy and paste a list of case statements in each action.

routes.rb

```
resources :advertiser_accounts, :type => "AdvertiserAccounts" do
    resources :campaigns
end
```

campaigns_controller.rb

```
def index
    case params[:type]
     when "AdvertiserAccounts"
            @account = current_user.accounts.find_by_id(params[:advertiser_account_id])
     when "PublisherAccounts"
            @account = current_user.accounts.find_by_id(params[:publisher_account_id])
    end
end
```

Comment: What does `rake routes` show, i.e. when i run rake routes i see this: http://cl.ly/1M2t2B1i1g290S2E353N as one of my entries, and I know `:id` is the id param

Comment: Oh. Thanks! I think my problem has to do with my routes file. My routes show, publisher_account_campaign GET    /publisher_accounts/:publisher_account_id/campaigns/:id(.:format) 

I am using the following to generate my routes in my routes.rb
resources :advertiser_accounts do
    resources :campaigns
end

How can I make my :publisher_account_id to be the parent :account_id? my STI account table does not have columns called :publisher_account_id

Comment: Thanks! I added :as => "accounts" in my routes and I think it solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
resources :advertiser_accounts, :as => "account" do
    resources :campaigns
end
```

that should give you

```
/advertiser_accounts/:account_id/campaigns/:id(.:format)
```

Comment: Quick question. How can I use :as but without changing the named path from advertiser_accounts to accounts? Right now when I use :as => "accounts" my routes turns to "account_campaigns GET    /advertiser_accounts/:account_id/campaigns(.:format)          campaigns#index". So when I create a new item using form_for, my advertiser_accounts_path would not exist since it got renamed. This would give me "undefined local variable or method `advertiser_accounts_path'"

Comment: Ya, i'm not sure there is a simple answer to that.  And i'm no Single table inheritance expert, but with my experience, I believe you should be able to call the Account Class record with the :advertiser_account_id without using `:as` at all right?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with "becomes" method in your controller.
In your private method where you're looking for the account_id you would have:

```
@account = Account.find(params[:account_id]).becomes Account
```